# Improper Limitation of a Pathname to a Restricted Directory ('Path Traversal') on Window.Open

Tags: javascript, security

I hit The following Javascript starting with ** is being flagged out as vulnerability : "Improper Limitation of a Pathname to a Restricted Directory ('Path Traversal')".Description : A variable is present in the filename argument of fs calls, this might allow an attacker to access anything on your system.

Why is this so and how do I resolve this ?

```
function d2hwindow(url, name)
    {
        if (name != 'main')
        {
            **var wnd = window.open(url, name, 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=0,directories=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,height=300,width=400');**
            wnd.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```